# How do you work with a programmer with a radically different coding style?

Tags: coding-style

Has anyone worked with a programmer with a radically different coding style?  How do you jive together without wanting to delete and rewrite each others code?

Comment: Why does this matter?  Does their stuff work?  Why does it have to look the same?

Comment: @S.Lott: It'll mess up diffs.

Comment: @S.Lott: code is read a lot. If understanding the code has the obstacle of being in an unfamiliar style, this can really add to maintenance cost.

Comment: “Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live.”
(Martin Golding)

Comment: Has anyone yet invented code-style cross compiler?? lol ;)

Comment: @Alfred: I have heard of discussions of having version control pre-commit hooks that would reformat source code. Not sure if descriptions included developers using an IDE which auto-formatted with their settings when they opened a file. In fact, this may all have been a dream...

Comment: Here you talk about two coworkers only, but this issue is really serious on medium or large projects... A coding standard is absolutely needed to work in teams to minimize maintenance cost and to enable communication

Comment: @Mehrdad Afshari: How will it mess up diffs?  Are you saying I would change their code simply to make it look the same and that would mess up the diffs?  Why would I do that?  How -- precisely -- will the diffs be messed up?

Comment: @Grundlefleck: While possibly true, it doesn't seem to be part of this question.  That's why I'm asking.  What is the real issue here?  Where is the problem?  What's broken (other than the relationship)?

Comment: @JuanZe: Why is a coding standard "absolutely needed"?  We have a mountain of open source on our project and the various standards don't match each other and don't match our in-house style.  What's the specific problem that will happen?  And -- when it comes to this question -- what specific problem is caused by differing styles?

Comment: @S.Lott: No, your IDE's autoformatting is likely to do that as you work on their code.

Comment: @S.Lott: that's a good point. I've addressed the same thing in my answer with "consider 'What are the benefits of having consistent code?'". I guess that we were left to infer the benefit that it's easier to work with.

Comment: @Mehrdad Afshari: What will my IDE do as I work on their code?  Why would an IDE mess up the diffs?  I'm having a lot of trouble following what you're claiming will happen.  I don't see what the problem is or how "consistent coding style" solves or prevents the problem.  Also, the question doesn't mention any of this, so I'm not sure your ideas will clarify this question very much.

Comment: Thanks everyone... This is why I posed this question... Everyone feels very passionately about the way they code.  I know I do.  We spend years perfecting our style and becomes our signature.. Just wondering if anyone else had to do this with a fellow programmer and how you came to an agreement.  Thanks!

Comment: @S.Lott: In C#, if you close a brace, the IDE will reformat the entire block. Assume I put braces on separate lines and my fellow dev doesn't do that. I check out his source and accidentally add an unnecessary } after adding a method to a class he has written. It'll trigger a reformatting. And when I check the file back in, you'll see a bunch of lines changed just for a brace. I assume "coding style" is primarily constituted by formatting.

Comment: @S.Lott I don't know what language you use but with my Java IDEs, if I open a file with a different code style, do some changes, I'll reformat the whole (and I think all developers do so, they don't reformat only the piece they added). So, yes, it's a concern to not use a unified code style (and yes, not doing so will mess the diffs).

Comment: @Pascal Thivent: "I'll reformat the whole"... So it's not the IDE?  It's something you did?  I'm really not clear on whether this is a technical issue or a personal issue.  All the examples sound personal.  I don't get what *real* problem is.  But it keeps sounding personal.

Comment: @S.Lott Of course it's the IDE but *I* type on my keyboard. My point is that I (and all other people I know) format a whole file, sometimes even a whole package, not only the sections I modify, this is the common use case (and actually, formatting is done automatically on save so that I never forget to do it). So if two people use different formatting rules between two commits, then it will mess the diff (marking a lot of files as changed even if it's just cosmetic). So no, this is not a personal issue.

Comment: @S.Lott To solve the formatting problem (which is just one aspect of coding style), one solution would be to format code on a pre-commit hook. This would allow everybody to use their own formatting rules during development. But, as I said, this is just one aspect of coding style. A team should just try to use the same standards (formatting, naming, documentation, etc): the project's standards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Pick one and go with it.**

If you are finding it hard to agree, take the time to list pros and cons including:

- **tool support for auto formatting** (*offhand I know Eclipse and Visual Studio can do this with a settings file*)
- **conformance to general industry standard** (*Sun have published standard conventions for Java, perhaps there is an equivalent in your language?*)
- **conformance to, or cost of modifying, pre-existing source** (*if you have a million lines in one style, how hard will it be to update that code to the new style?*)
- **... any other factor which either of you find is important** (*this can include the cost to become familiar with the new style*)

If you find yourself working with someone too stubborn to change and adapt, well, you have a bigger problem than clashing code style, and dealing with that is out of scope for this question.

If you are the person to adapt your style, avoid the statement "Well if we had chose *my* way...". If you have agreed on a single style, fully commit to it.

Before getting to this point though, you should probably ask yourself: what are the benefits of having consistent code? You may find that the cost of consistent code (annoying the other developer) is not worth the benefit.

Comment: I think your right.  Its about prioritizing.  I know 2 people will never have the same style.. its like having 2 authors on a book.  But agreeing on what is important.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

We agree on a standard coding style and enforce it in the form of Visual Studio settings files.

Comment: I don't find this really answers the question. It's the "agree on a standard coding style" which the OP is asking about, not the mechanism for a particular tool. That's just kind of glossed over...

Comment: @Grundlefleck: I don't think it's a serious problem unless one guy wants to deliberately make religious arguments (if that's the case, you have bigger problems). The real problem comes down to enforcing coding style instead of your habits which is done by the IDE with the settings file.

Comment: @Myself: retracted. This does address the "jive together" part :-)

Comment: We do the same with Eclipse :-)

Comment: Hahah yeah... for all intents and purposes our code absolutely works, together and separate.  We even share the same variable naming convention.. but the the methods of doing things like logically.

Comment: I don't think you can change the way people think and it's direct consequence: their code. You'll have to get over it.

Answer (score 6):

That's a human communication issue. Just talk to each other. Not through code, in person.

Comment: What do you do if the other person just states "I've always used this style, and I'm not going to change it. I don't care if you use another style."

Comment: You ask your boss to mediate.  If he is the boss, you adopt his style.  If his style is so bad that you can't and he is the boss, you find another job or live with it.

Answer (score 5):

Communicate with the other developer.
Agree on a coding style that combines best of both worlds ?

Answer (score 4):

- using the IDE in combination with style-checking plugins (In the Java case - Checkstyle, PMD) the team leader, or even the project manager (if a technical person) can force code style guidelines upon the whole team.
- just ignore his style - I have worked on Java projects where some developers were putting the curly brackets on a new line, and tended to forget spaces where they are generally needed - and I didn't have any problem with it after the fist week.
- discuss the code-styles and compromise, then apply the IDE capabilities mentioned in the first point.

Answer (score 4):

When you say "coding style" do you mean formatting or a difference in the way you structure your code ?

As for coding style, the team should probably have a style formatter and enforce some kind of format before commit. this way merges will not drive the merger crazy.

For the structural difference in the code I am afraid there is no easy solution. If one is a hard core spaghetti coder, versus a fanatical object coder you will have to sit down at a table and discuss both approaches and how they apply on your particular project. Remeber that there is no absolute answer, it all depends on context. 
Also try resorting to someone both of you respect to recommand best practices, do code review for code validation, and help determine a common approach (technical leader or tech PM).

Comment: It is part spacing and look.. but its also methods of doing things.  I want to be able to look at his code and be able to expand on it easily.. and him my code.  We duplicate some work just to call our own style methods.

Answer (score 2):

I’m going to answer on the “soft skills” required to get along with someone who has vastly different coding style that me. Generally I try to focus on three simple principles; professionalism, trust and ego.

In terms of professionalism its simple unacceptable to simply re-write or delete someone’s code because their style is different than yours. A professional approach would be to first understand why I consider my ideas/style/preferences to be better. Then I would expect to sit down with the other person and discuss my points and, here’s the important part, keep an open mind. Just because I like my idea doesn’t mean that it’s right or correct. A true professional will be able and willing to accept that others ideas are just as valuable and come from a different perspective.

I personally need to trust my fellow developers. The old saying is that trust must be earned not brought and this is true for software development. Trust can be built on from a variety of sources like sharing information, ideas and code. A productive team usually has an implicit level of trust between its developers.

One of the major reasons that people don’t get along is ego. Our egos allow us to feel threatened, superior, embarrassed and a variety of other human emotions. Leaving our egos aside and talking about our issues with the other person is always a good start.

Answer (score 2):

**Your** coding style is not the norm. **His** coding style is not the norm. **The** norm is the coding style chosen by the project or, sometimes, the whole organization (and that should be documented somewhere) and both of you have to comply to it. Tools like Checkstyle (with Java) can be used to ensure conformance. If you use such a tool, distribute its configuration file. Also distribute files for IDEs formatting configuration.

Many open source (or corporate) projects do use these principles (see for example XWiki's [Java Code Style](http://dev.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Community/JavaCodeStyle), [Maven Code Style And Code Conventions](http://maven.apache.org/developers/conventions/code.html) or [Apache Developers' C Language Style Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/dev/styleguide.html)). This works for developers distributed around the world, don't tell me this can't work for developers in a same room.

If your project doesn't have any code standards, then it's maybe time to define some and I just hope you will be able to do it as two adults (actually, this should be a team decision). If necessary, remind why an unified code style is important (for a better readability, for diffs). If, sadly, this doesn't work, then have a boss decide for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have to work with developers everyday that have vastly different coding styles to mine and as a developer, you learn to deal with it.

You have 4 choices, 
- you either convert them
- you get converted
- you propose a company standard.
- you live with it.

If it's something like prepending the variable with the type, argue the point that a variable should be descriptive enough so that it type can be inferred.

personName vs sPersonName vs strPersonName <-- which one would you choose?

if you mean formatting,
ctrl-a, k f <-- formats your code nicely in VS :)

Answer (score 1):

I find it rare that there is only one other developer with whom I have to agree on coding styles, and that different groups or projects have different styles. You have to learn to adapt to different coding styles.

If there are only two of you, then there are only two of you who need to agree on the common coding style you are going to use.

If you cannot agree on a coding style, then you just have to deal with it. Try to work in a way that is productive -- and that means not rewriting the other person's code just to get it to match your style.

There may be some stylistic aspects that are troublesome, and it is best to focus on those. Style can easily turn into a religious discussion, so it's often more effective to focus on quantitative or empirical arguments for changes. Elegancy and physical beauty of your code may not win the argument -- but showing cases where a stylistic change would have headed off unnecessary debugging can be effective.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If the other developer isn't particularly easy going, then I tend to just go with their programming style even if I disagree with it rather than force the issue - in this case its really a matter of **whats more uncomfortable, their coding style or the grief I'll get by making a fuss?**

If the other developer is more open minded then I might discuss things like coding / naming standards (I would hope that things like the overall architecture would be discussed anyway)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to invent some style suitable for both of you and stick to it. And if communication is a problem, just stick to an idea: "when I write my own, I don't touch the other code"